# Match specific data in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, relational-database, match

In Microsoft Access I have a table of payments and a table with the promises that collection officers made.

[image]

I want to assign to the payment table by id (and date) the last collection officer that made the agreement with the debtor.

For example: On id 1111 there were two promises made: by Morticia Adams and Gulliver; But i choose Gulliver because he made the last promise in that date range taking in account the date of payment.

Likewise for id 5425 the last promise made was made by Marie Anne because 23.10.2016 (date of payment) is between 12.10.2016 and 26.10.2016 (promise dates).

This is already done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325328/vlookup-on-another-table-with-multiple-criteria) in Excel but in need this to be done in Microsoft Access since I have a huge table and Excel takes a long time to process the information.

As an idea it must satisfy the following conditions:

> - The payment ID of the row in the promises table is equal to the payment id of the payments table.
> - The date of the payment is greater than or equal to the conversation date.
> - The date of the payment is less than or equal to the agreed payment date.

I would be really grateful if someone could give me a hint.

Comment: This isn't a jobs board where you "hire" someone to help you. YOU write the code, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: This isn't a simple inner join and I have no ideea how to do it. Maybe you could give me a hint Marc B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you'd split the query into two queries using inner joins, but you can do it with one.

Using this:

```
SELECT [Payments Table].ID, [Payments Table].[Date of Payment], [Payment Promises Table].[Collection Officer]
FROM ([Payments Table] 
    INNER JOIN 
        ( SELECT [Payments Table].ID, Max([Payment Promises Table].[Date of conversation]) AS LastDate
        FROM [Payments Table] INNER JOIN [Payment Promises Table] ON [Payments Table].ID = [Payment Promises Table].ID
        WHERE ((([Payments Table].[Date of Payment]) Between [Date of Conversation] And [Date Agreed to Pay]))
        GROUP BY [Payments Table].ID) AS FindOfficer
    ON [Payments Table].ID = FindOfficer.ID) 
INNER JOIN [Payment Promises Table] 
ON (FindOfficer.LastDate = [Payment Promises Table].[Date of conversation]) 
AND (FindOfficer.ID = [Payment Promises Table].ID);
```

Comes up with this:

[image: Screenshot of query results]

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. It helps when you describe your data and goals so well